# Beginner, making a Console based RPG in C# but having a problem

Tags: c#, console-application

Here's what I have so far: The player can type commands like North, East, South, West, And Help, and it works. My problem comes when I implement a Look command. I log the description from the current room, however it never changes. I *belive*, the problem may have to do with those mystical reference and value types, but I'm not experienced enough to be sure, or how to fix it. 
**However**, when I put Console.WriteLine(CurrentRoom.RoomDescription) under any currentRoom.SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player), it works just fine.

Main Class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Room currentRoom;
        List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
        Player player = new Player();

        //Rooms
        Room startingRoom = new Room("Starting room", "This is the starting room", 0, 0);
        Room northRoom = new Room("North room", "This is the north room", 0, 1);
        Room eastRoom = new Room("East room", "This is the east room", 1, 0);
        Room southRoom = new Room("South room", "This is the south room", 0, -1);
        Room westRoom = new Room("West room", "This is the west room", -1, 0);

        //Add and set starting room as current room
        rooms.Add(startingRoom);
        currentRoom = startingRoom;

        //Adding rooms
        rooms.Add(northRoom);
        rooms.Add(eastRoom);
        rooms.Add(southRoom);
        rooms.Add(westRoom);

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Dungeon. This is the starting room.");
        GetHelp();
        Console.WriteLine("There are four exits. Which way do you want to go?");
        while (true)
        {
            HandleInput(player, currentRoom, rooms);
        }



    }

    private static void GetHelp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You can move to locations by entering 'North', 'East', 'South', and 'West'.");
        Console.WriteLine("You can also examine the room by entering 'Look'.");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'Help' at any time to view instructions.");
    }

    private static Room SetCurrentRoom(List<Room> rooms, Player player)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (room.XPos == player.PlayerXPos && room.YPos == player.PlayerYPos)
            {
                return room;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid direction.");

        return null;

    }

    private static void HandleInput(Player player, Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "North")
        {
            player.Move(Direction.Directions.North);
            currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);


        }
        else if (input == "East")
        {
            player.Move(Direction.Directions.East);
            currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);


        }
        else if (input == "South")
        {
            player.Move(Direction.Directions.South);
            currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);


        }
        else if (input == "West")
        {
            player.Move(Direction.Directions.West);
            currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);

        }
        else if (input == "Help")
        {
            GetHelp();
        }
        else if (input == "Look")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentRoom.RoomDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }

    }
}
```

Room Class:

```
public class Room
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string RoomDescription { get; set; }
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }

    public Room(string roomName, string roomDescription, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        this.RoomName = roomName;
        this.RoomDescription = roomDescription;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;

    }
}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PlayerXPos { get; set; }
    public int PlayerYPos { get; set; }

    public void Move(Direction.Directions direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Directions.North:
                PlayerYPos += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving north");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.East:
                PlayerXPos += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving east.");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.South:
                PlayerYPos -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving south.");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.West:
                PlayerXPos -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving west.");
                break;

        }
    }


}
```

Direction Class:

```
public class Direction
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        North,
        East,
        South,
        West
    }
}
```

I am a beginner, so the code may be revolting to an experienced programmer.

Comment: @stuartd I'm glad my code is alright. Then I guess my question changes to "How do I debug?". I have some brief experience with debugging in an online course on C# I took, but it never really set. I set a breakpoint, but the controls and watch items are greyed out.

Comment: Worth spending time just trying setting breakpoints and stepping through code - it woudn't really have helped you understand what was happening here, but it's an inaluable skill to have.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe, the problem may have to do with those mystical reference and value types

You are very close. The problem is because the `currentRoom` is passed to the `HandleInput` method 'by value' instead of 'by reference', but you are trying to assign a different `Room` to it.

The signature of your `HandleInput` method is this:

```
private static void HandleInput(Player player, Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
```

In the method you are trying to set `currentRoom`to another `Room`.

But by default when something is passed to a method it is passed 'by value', which means you can change properties on that variable, but you cannot change the **actual** variable it refers to - like in `currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);` - unless you pass it 'by reference', like this:

```
private static void HandleInput(Player player, ref Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
```

In which case you would then have to call it like this:

```
HandleInput(player, ref currentRoom, rooms);
```

What the `ref` keyword  means is that the method you call can change the 'underlying object' that the value type `currentRoom` refers to.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to do with the base value being called, but I couldn't tell why it wasn't changing. Good to know how to step around that, now Value and Reference types are a little less intimidating.

Comment: The naming doesn't help - "reference and value types are passed by value, unless you say they should be passed by reference"..